# How to change the font for a specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, css, frontend, fonts

I have two store-views which are English and Persian(RTL) and would like to change the font of the Persian store-view for all front-end contents.

Magento ver 1.9.2.4

Comment: Which theme you are using ?

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies  I use SM Market theme.

Comment: Ask theme provider they provide RTL theme

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies, Yeah of course they do, I want to change the font of a store-view which is already up in RTL.

Comment: Check that from which file that come I mean CSS and try to change from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new child theme of your regular store theme, only with necessary customizations, like adding another CSS file (via XML) and fonts files, then set this theme to your Persian store.

Answer (score 0):

Create a skin theme with only CSS and change it based on store view or store or website.